# In holoviews, how do I sort categorical axes of an Overlay?

Tags: python, holoviews

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 categorical columns (A,B,C), and 1 numeric (N). I plot a scatter plot with x-axis A, y-axis N, and stratified by B (lets just make this binary for ease of reference). There is thus a dot for every A-C combination, colored by B (2-colors). This results in a NdLayout object.

Now I am trying to get the order of the x-axis right, where the values are ordered by the absolute sum of values for that category (irrespective of strata, ie B).

If I simply sort the entries of A in the dataframe based on a group sum, it works for most cases. However in one case, there is no A-C entry for a particular strata of B, ie there is missing data. For example if B=1, then a value of A does not exist for that strata, but does exist for B=0. So when plotting this, the value gets added to the wrong place, as I am using NdLayout.

Is there a post plot process to change the factor ordering in a dimension?

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("matplotlib")
import colorcet as cc

ds = hv.Dataset(data,kdims=["A"],vdims=["N","B"])
scatter = ds.to(hv.Scatter,"A","N","B").overlay().opts(opts.Scatter(color=hv.Cycle([cc.isolum[0]] + [cc.isolum[-1]]),xrotation=90))
```

Example:

```
A = ['Sample_{}'.format(ii) for ii in range(20)]
C = ['Category_{}'.format(ii) for ii in range(10)]
b_data = np.asarray([np.random.normal(0,xx+1,size=10) for xx in range(20)])

B_1 = pd.DataFrame(b_data,index=A,columns=C)
B_1 = B_1.rename_axis('A').reset_index().melt(id_vars='A',value_name='N',var_name='C')
B_1['B'] = 1

#create data set with one of the Sample_ entries removed.
b_data = np.asarray([np.random.normal(0,xx+1,size=10) for xx in range(19)])
B_0 = pd.DataFrame(b_data,index=A[:-1],columns=C)
B_0 = B_0.rename_axis('A').reset_index().melt(id_vars='A',value_name='N',var_name='C')
B_0['B'] = 0

myData = pd.concat([B_1,B_0])

featureOrder = myData.groupby('A')['N'].apply(lambda x: x.abs().sum()).sort_values(ascending=False).index
myData['A'] = pd.Categorical(myData.A, categories=featureOrder,ordered=True)
myData =myData.sort_values(by='A')

#generate plot using hvplot
myData.hvplot.scatter(x='A',y='N',by='B').opts(padding=0.1,xrotation=90)

#the following gives the same output, but doesn't use hvplot
ds = hv.Dataset(myData,kdims=["A"],vdims=["N","B"])
scatter = ds.to(hv.Scatter,"A","N","B").overlay().opts(opts.Scatter(color=hv.Cycle([cc.isolum[0]] + [cc.isolum[-1]]),xrotation=90))
```

```
print(featureOrder)
Index(['Sample_17', 'Sample_18', 'Sample_13', 'Sample_16', 'Sample_11',
       'Sample_15', 'Sample_14', 'Sample_10', 'Sample_19', 'Sample_12',
       'Sample_9', 'Sample_6', 'Sample_8', 'Sample_7', 'Sample_5', 'Sample_4',
       'Sample_3', 'Sample_2', 'Sample_1', 'Sample_0'],
      dtype='object', name='A')
```

[image]

From the plot Sample_19 is added to the end, while it should be 9th. If I change the values of B around, then the plot is in the correct order.

Comment: I have troubles following your question. Could you construct an example of `data`? Also, is what you're actually trying to achieve "choose one colour per value of B"?

Comment: @doppler added an example

Comment: So your question is about "ordering categorical axes"? There's an open issue for that, see here https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/issues/3799 and in the referenced hvplot issue. The short version is that you have to pre-sort the dataframe, no sorting is done on the holoviews end.

Comment: On the other hand, I still don't understand by which logic Sample_19 must be in the 9th position. What is your expectation why it should be there and not in the first or 5th (or last, for that matter)?

Comment: @doppler You are correct that the question is related to the ordering of the categorical axes. I am aware of the issue linked, and I do sort the dataframe beforehand. The specific issue here is that in the case of missing data, the ordering breaks down (Sample_19 is contained in the B=1 data set, but not in the B=0 data set). Sample_19 should be in the 9th position, as you can see from the print out of the `featureOrder` object, which resulted from descending order sort of the absolute sum of N for each category A. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Ah, I see, I was confused by the slightly chaotic categories. I modified the title of your question to reflect our discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example above, if you compare `scatter[1] * scatter[0]` with `scatter[0] * scatter[1]`, you'll see that it's the first element of an Overlay that defines the order of categorical axes, and the rest is just appended (as you already found out).

One workaround for now is inserting NaNs for all missing data that you'd like to be part of the ordering.

(For a more general approach to sorting of categorical axes, that is the stuff of several recent issues and will hopefully be implemented some day - see github issues linked in my comments.)